# appropriate credit for using a code posted on stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I have a more general question regarding StackExchange (Sorry if this is not the right place to post such a "meta-question"): When I use a code posted here for, lets say, doing some research and I publish this research how do I give appropriate credit (attribution) for using this code?

see here: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/Y

Do I need to give credit at all?

Comment: See the replies here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126414/what-is-the-correct-way-to-attribute-a-stack-overflow-answer-in-my-code

Comment: oh perfect, thx!

Comment: Retrieval should be dated, too, imo, like any piece of information retrieved from online. Honestly it wouldn’t be too much to include a copy of a saved/archive of the source code of the site with your paper either.